# Yup .when validation with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

I'm converting a validation schema from `jsx` to a `tsx` filetype. It works perfectly in `jsx` but in `tsx` I can't get the type for the yup `when` condition to pass. Even `any` fails to pass. Any idea how to type this correctly?
The error appearing is

`Argument of type '(startTime: Date) => Yup.DateSchema<Date | undefined, Record<string, any>, Date | undefined> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConditionOptions<RequiredDateSchema<Date | undefined, Record<string, any>>>'.`

`Type '(startTime: Date) => Yup.DateSchema<Date | undefined, Record<string, any>, Date | undefined> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ConditionBuilder<RequiredDateSchema<Date | undefined, Record<string, any>>>'.`

`Type 'DateSchema<Date | undefined, Record<string, any>, Date | undefined> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'SchemaLike'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SchemaLike'.  TS2345`

My validation:

```
Yup.date().required('This field is required')
            .when('startTime', (startTime: Date) => { // <-- this is where error appears
                if (startTime) {
                    return Yup.date()
                        .min(startTime, 'End must be after Start')
                        .typeError('End is required')
                }
            }),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest thing:

```
Yup.date().required('This field is required')
            .when('startTime', (startTime: Date) => {
                if (startTime) {
                    return Yup.date()
                        .min(startTime, 'End must be after Start')
                        .typeError('End is required')
                } 
                return Yup.date()
            })
```

Personally I would prefer:

```
Yup.date()
  .required("This field is required")
  .when("startTime", (startTime) =>
    startTime
      ? Yup.date()
          .min(startTime, "End must be after Start")
          .typeError("End is required")
      : Yup.date()
  );
```

but that is just clean up.

Comment: This answer doesn't match the question. Editor give the following error: 
"TS2769: No overload matches this call", the software did word but it's ugly to see this error on editor

Answer (score 0):

The reason Typescript show you this error is because you didn't specified the return type.

```
.when('x_lifetime_type', (values: string[], schema: NumberSchema): NumberSchema => {
  if (values.indexOf('seconds') >= 0) {
     return schema.min(60, 'Minimum value is 1 minute');
  } else { return schema; }
})
```

In this example, input and output schema are typed with `NumberSchema`. PD: You have to use `schema` parameter to sum adicional validations.